# Java / Ebeans SQLException

Tags: java, mysql, ebean

Error

```
Query threw SQLException:'49180950926' in column '1' 
is outside valid range for the datatype INTEGER. Bind values:[] 
Query was:SELECT * from myTable WHERE myData= ?
```

My Row Object (Java)

```
@Id
@Column(name="idMyObject")
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long myData;
```

Java Call to get data

```
MyDataRow row = mostEm.findNative(MyDataRow.class, 
"SELECT * from myTablle WHERE myData= ?")
.setParameter(1, Long.parseLong(myDataString))
.findOne();
```

SQL Row Info

```
myData   bigint(20)
```

I have tried multiple ways to get this to work but I am always getting the error listed above. I am not sure exactly where to turn.

Comment: what you have in myDataString?

Comment: The number from the error message. It gets built as a string with different pieces appended and then parsed to long in the request

Comment: You need to show what MyDataRow looks like (property types) and what the DDL looks like that creates the table and probably what database you are using (mysql, postgres etc).